# Transferring the rows from one table to another in angular 2 using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to transfer selected rows from one table to another.I have implemented a sample stack-blitz example which can be accessed using https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-material-h2lcps?file=app%2Faccount%2Faccount.component.html

Using the above example I am gettinmg the following output in my console.

[image]

Here I have implemented the **Remove selected Rows** button.But I am unable to implement **Transfer Selected Rows** button.

Can anybody please guide me how can i implement this transfer functionality...?

Comment: Provided stackblitz isn't working

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide..... Yes even I am getting " angular-app-material-h2lcps.stackblitz.io’s server IP address could not be found. " in output window ...! How can I avoid this..?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon... I dont have any errors ... but when i select the rows from the table i want to display those rows in the another table ..!

Comment: so you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: just give me clue i will do it hopefully...

Comment: in which case, yes, you do want it writing. try it yourself and come back if you have any issues or errors

Comment: ok wait ............

Comment: @mast3rd3mon.... can you please check this link ....https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-material-h2lcps?file=app%2Faccount%2Faccount.component.ts

Comment: i have altered the transferselectedrows( ) method...

Comment: i am able display the selected row in console ...but i am unable display in my output window...!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167565/discussion-between-heena-and-mast3rd3mon).

Comment: well i think you need a service that recieve the selected rows then send it to you component or window, or if your want to display in the same window need to do another table and another datasource object

Comment: yup.... even i was thinking of creating a service ... well i will try this one....

Comment: your ngFor need to be like this   <p *ngFor ="let i of item">{{i.position}}</p>

Comment: I recomend create an array called selectedRows or something like this, then in your transferSelectedRows when find the index do "this.selectedRows.push(this.data[i])" before your splice it, then change item on ngFor by selectedRows  <p *ngFor ="let i of selectedRows">{{i.position}}</p>

Answer (score 0):

I can just give you hint. I have done swapping between grids in my project. I am using kendo-grid.

First on a selection of checkbox I took one array in which I push my selected row data. After that on swap button click( swapping from right to left ), I push data in left grid data and splice data from right grid data by checking both data positions.

This might help you with your problem. Code for swapping is much longer in my project because there are many validations too. So I providing you with some of my code.

```
OnSelectionChange(){
 if (event.selectedRows.length > 0 && event.selectedRows[0].dataItem != undefined) {
            for (let i = 0; i < event.selectedRows.length; i++) {
                this.rightGridSelectedData.push(event.selectedRows[i].dataItem);
            }
        }
        else if (event.deselectedRows.length > 0) {
            for (var index = 0; index < this.rightGridSelectedData.length; index++) {
                if (this.rightGridSelectedData[index].featureID === event.deselectedRows[0].dataItem.featureID && this.rightGridSelectedData[index].moduleID === event.deselectedRows[0].dataItem.moduleID) {
                    this.rightGridSelectedData.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for your feedback ... i havent thought of array ... this might help me...